# gradle: how to remove task dependency

Tags: gradle

Gradle makes it easy to add task dependencies at runtime.

Is it also possible to remove a task dependency after it has been added?

As a use case, let's say we want to run checkstyle in a separate pipeline step, not as part of the main build. So, we apply the `checkstyle` plugin, but that adds some tasks that depend on `check`. I would like to break that dependency, so that `checkstyle` only runs when explicitly run, not as part of `build` (which depends on `check`, which depends on `checkstyle*`).

To accomplish the above, I could run the main pipeline step as `build -x checkstyleMain -x checkstyleTest`.
Another workaround would be to set the `enabled` property of the checkstyle tasks to false.

But for this question, I am interested in a generic way to remove a task dependency so that the task graph is missing the edge between 2 tasks, like that dependency was never added.
The problem is not an easy one because:

- removing a dependency before it was added won't have any effect
- trying to remove a dependency on `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady` will probably fail (since it's no longer allowed to change the task graph.

A good answer would also be that this is for sure not possible, in which case I could raise a feature request with the Gradle team.

##### Update 1

I tried to convert @Chriki's groovy to kotlin, like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.check {
        dependsOn -= tasks.find {
            it.name.startsWith("checkstyle")
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error: "Removing a task dependency from a task instance is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to great [@Chriki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797912/chriki) answer, I've got mine as well. Leaving it here for others to use it.

I'm using `quarkus` and annotation processing. When upgraded to newer version, I had circular dependencies:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:kspKotlin
+--- :quarkusGenerateCode
|    \--- :processResources
|         \--- :kspKotlin (*)
\--- :quarkusGenerateCodeDev
     \--- :processResources (*)
```

In order to break that, I used the following code in my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
    project.afterEvaluate {
        tasks.findByPath("application:quarkusGenerateCode")?.let {
            it.setDependsOn(it.dependsOn.map { it as Provider<*> }.filter { it.get() !is ProcessResources })
        }
        tasks.findByPath("application:quarkusGenerateCodeDev")?.let {
            it.setDependsOn(it.dependsOn.map { it as Provider<*> }.filter { it.get() !is ProcessResources })
        }
    }
```

If you have more than one module that has circular dependency, you may want to use this snippet, as it searches through all modules:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    getTasksByName("quarkusGenerateCode", true).forEach { task ->
        task.setDependsOn(task.dependsOn.map { it as Provider<Task> }.filter { it.get().name != "processResources" })
    }
    getTasksByName("quarkusGenerateCodeDev", true).forEach { task ->
        task.setDependsOn(task.dependsOn.map { it as Provider<Task> }.filter { it.get().name != "processResources" })
    }
}
```

It assumes that provider is a type Task and searches the breaking dependency by name.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `./gradlew bar` on the following self-contained build, will not run the `foo` task, even though it was declared as a dependency of `bar` (tested with Gradle 7.1):

```groovy
task foo {
    doFirst {
        println 'foo'
    }
}


task bar {
    dependsOn foo
    doFirst {
        println 'bar'
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    bar.dependsOn -= foo
}
```

In your case, you could hence add something like the following to your `build.gradle` to unconditionally remove the undesired Checkstyle task dependencies from the `check` task:

```groovy
project.afterEvaluate {
    check.dependsOn -= checkstyleMain
    check.dependsOn -= checkstyleTest
}
```

---

Using the Kotlin DSL, the following works for my build script above:

```kotlin
project.afterEvaluate {
    val bar = tasks.findByPath("bar")
    if (bar != null) {
        bar.setDependsOn(bar.dependsOn - listOf(tasks.findByPath("foo"), "foo"))
    }
}
```

It’s important *not* to use the `-=` operator.

Please excuse the verbosity. I’m sure this can be written more concisely but I’m not fluent enough in Kotlin.

Comment: It doesn't work for me using Kotlin. I get an error (see Update 1 in the question). Unless I made a mistake in the conversion to Kotlin, I assume it won't work in Groovy also, right?

Comment: As I had mentioned, I tested this and it _is_ working with the Groovy DSL. I’ve provided a translation of the crucial part to Kotlin (also successfully tested with Gradle 7.1).

Comment: It doesn't work trying to remove the dependency from "check" to "checkstyleMain". `tasks.findByPath("checkstyleMain")` returns a `Checkstyle_Decorated` class, while the items in `check.dependsOn` are some anonymous inner classes of `AbstractCodeQualityPlugin`, so the minus operator doesn't return any less items.

I don't have time to debug more now, but when I make some time, I'll take a look into this.