# Unable to remove Gradle task from dependsOn

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I was trying to do a very simple (in theory) thing - remove one task dependency on another one. I'm using Gradle `nu.studer.jooq` plugin and it comes with task `generateJooq` which somehow makes other tasks depend on it (compileJava & compileKotlin).

Something like (taskTree):

```
:db:compileJava
+--- :db:compileKotlin
|    \--- :db:generateJooq
\--- :db:generateJooq *
```

I used an approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68822357/10371394

```kotlin
project.afterEvaluate {
    val generateJooq = tasks.findByPath("generateJooq")
    this.tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        setDependsOn(dependsOn - setOf(generateJooq))
    }
}
```

But it simply doesn't work. I have tried debug printing `dependsOn` variable - it prints nothing, the collection is empty. And yet somehow `generateJooq` gets called every time I execute `compileKotlin`. I want to remove such dependency to only run it manually whenever needed.

Gradle: 8.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency on the `generateJooq` task is automatically applied to Java compilation tasks. This behavior can be disabled as described in the plugin [documentation itself](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#generating-the-jooq-sources). Set `JookConfig#generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation` property value to `false`.

Example:

```
jooq {
  configurations {
    create("main") {
      generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's that simple.. My bad I didn't check plugin docs. Thank you

Comment: Your approach would work if plugin would define explicitly task dependency between generateJooq and Kotlin / Java compilation. While dependency is implicitly set through [java input source files also explained in comment](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/main/src/main/groovy/nu/studer/gradle/jooq/JooqPlugin.java#L50 ). It's known as [inferred task dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:inferred_task_dependencies)